# How to refer to root in connect.server()?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm using gulp-connect, I have all my .html files in my project root directory.

This is my gruntfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('connect', connect.server({
    root: '/',
    port: 8000,
    livereload: true,
    open: {
        file: 'index.html'
    }
}));
```

I have tried `root: ''`, `root: '.'` as well as declare nothing, they were all not working with 404 file not found error, but if I moved my .html to sub directory such as *dist* and declare `root: 'dist'`, it was working.

How do I setup the root option of connect.server() to look for files in my project's root directory?

Comment: Personally, I'd [skip the unnecessary plugin](http://blog.overzealous.com/post/74121048393/why-you-shouldnt-create-a-gulp-plugin-or-how-to-stop), and just use connect yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I get it working using `root: [__dirname]`

Comment: You can also do path = require('path') and then root: path.resolve('./')

Comment: Default directory is directory with `gulpfile` as per [docs](https://github.com/avevlad/gulp-connect#optionsroot)